# Split Screen in Kivy?

Tags: python, kivy

I want to create a simple app in Kivy, but I want to split the main display in two sections. The top part will have some buttons and it will stay fixed. However, in the bottom part I want to switch between different screens. Is this possible?

Here is a simplified version:

```
<home screen>:
        BoxLayout:

               Button:


               Screen: 
                  (Switch between Screen 1, and 2)



<screen 1>

<screen 2>
```

I would really appreciate some help. Thank you!

---

Ok, here is my non working example.

.py File:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout

class HomeScreen(Screen):
    pass

class Screen1(Screen):
    pass

class Screen2(Screen):
    pass

class SplitScreenApp(App):
    def build(self):

        sm = ScreenManager()
        sm.add_widget(HomeScreen(name='home_screen'))
        sm.add_widget(Screen1(name='screen_one'))
        sm.add_widget(Screen2(name='screen_two'))

        return sm
if __name__ == "__main__":
    SplitScreenApp().run()
```

.kv File

```
<HomeScreen>:

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        rows: 3

        ScreenManager:
            size_hint_y: 0.8

        Button:
            size_hint_y: 0.1
            on_press:
                root.manager.transition.direction = 'left'
                root.manager.current = 'screen_one'
        Button:
            size_hint_y: 0.1
            on_press:
                root.manager.transition.direction = 'left'
                root.manager.current = 'screen_two'


<Screen1>:

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        rows: 1
        Button:
            text: "Screen 1"

<Screen2>:

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        rows: 1
        Button:
            text: "Screen 2"
```

So I expect to see "Screen 1" show first on top of the two Buttons. Then, I can press one of the two in "HomeScreen" and it will switch between "Screen 1" and "Screen 2" on press.

Comment: @inclement Can you help me fix the code I added please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ask this a while back - and based on the feedback I received here I got the following code working for me. Perhaps, this will help someone else.

Python File:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout

class HomeScreen(BoxLayout):
    pass

class Screen1(Screen):
    pass

class SplitScreenApp(App):
    def build(self):

        return HomeScreen()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    SplitScreenApp().run()
```

Kivy Code:

```
<HomeScreen>:
    name: 'ScreenManager'
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        rows: 3

        ScreenManager:
            id: sm
            size_hint_y: 0.8

            Screen1:

            Screen:
                name: "screen_two"
                BoxLayout:
                    orientation: 'vertical'
                    rows: 1
                    Button:
                        text: "Screen 2"
                        on_release: sm.current = 'screen_one'

        Button:
            text: "Screen 1"
            size_hint_y: 0.1
            on_press:
                sm.transition.direction = 'left'
                sm.current = 'screen_one'
        Button:
            text: "Screen 2"
            size_hint_y: 0.1
            on_press:
                sm.transition.direction = 'left'
                sm.current = 'screen_two'

<Screen1>:
    name: "screen_one"
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        rows: 1
        Button:
            text: "Screen 1 Out"
            on_release: root.parent.current = 'screen_two'
```

Thanks again to everybody that is willing to help here.

Answer (score 3):

Certainly, just replace Screen with ScreenManager in your example and add whatever Screens you like to it.

If you have a specific problem, post an example with real code demonstrating what you think should work and how it fails.

Comment: Thank you for you reply. I added my real example above but it does not work. Truth is I have no clue how to place the screens under the ScreenManager.

Answer (score 1):

You lack a reference to the screenmanager object, and your homescreen should be just another screen under the screenmanager, with the buttons on a separate Layout.

Have you checked out the examples which come with kivy? The 'showcase' one does pretty much exactly what you want.

Comment: Thank you! That was a good reference but the Screens under the ScreenMenager are in the same class in the showcase. I wanted to have separate classes for each screen ← for no good reason at the moment.

Comment: You should probably check out the documentation on 'rules', there's no such thing as 'in the same class', each screen is just inheriting from the same Screen subclass and you can put them in different parts of the kv file without a problem (just name them something else which inherits from Screen).